# Using action in Screen to effect event in other screen

Tags: python, screen, kivy

I'm trying to create a kivy app that contains two screens, a selection screen which determines what video url to retrieve, and a screen containing a video player that will play back the desired video.

What I want to happen is for the user to click the 'Load Video' button on the selection screen and have that change the state of the video player to 'play', but I can't for the life of me figure out how to reference the video player in order to enact the change.

Python file:

```
import kivy, datetime, 
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from calendar import monthrange

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

class SelectionScreen(Screen):
play = ObjectProperty(None)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
videoscreen = ObjectProperty(None)

monthlist = []
for monthnumber in range(1,13):
    monthlist.append(str("%02d"%monthnumber))
yearlist = []
for yearnumber in reversed(range(now.year-10,now.year+1)):
    yearlist.append(str(yearnumber))
daylist = []
for daynumber in range(1, (monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]+1)):
    daylist.append(str("%02d"%daynumber))

class VideoScreen(Screen):
pass        

class RacingReplayApp(App):
def build(self):  
     sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
     sm.add_widget(SelectionScreen(name='selectionscr'))
     sm.add_widget(VideoScreen(name='videoscr'))
     return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
RacingReplayApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<SelectionScreen>:
FloatLayout:        
    size: root.size 
    pos: root.pos
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, .2, .3
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size     
    Spinner:
        id: day_spinner
        text: 'Day'
        values: root.daylist
        size_hint: (None, None)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .35, 'center_y': .75}
    Spinner:
        id: month_spinner
        text: 'Month'
        values: root.monthlist
        size_hint: (None, None)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .75}
    Spinner:
        id: year_spinner
        text: 'Year'
        values: root.yearlist
        size_hint: (None, None)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .65, 'center_y': .75}
    Button:
        id: play
        text: 'Load Video'
        font_size: 16
        size_hint: (.2, .1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'videoscr'

<VideoScreen>:
FloatLayout:        
    size: root.size 
    pos: root.pos
    Video:
        id: videostream
        source: 'URL_GOES_HERE'
        fullscreen: True
        state: 'stop'
```

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

**edit:**

As sirpercival pointed out below, each screen has an 'on_enter' method attached to it. All I did was add the following to the kv file:

```
<VideoScreen>:
    on_enter: videostream.state = 'play'
    FloatLayout:
```

Now when the 'Load Video' button is clicked, the app will enter the Video Screen and trigger the on_enter method, causing the video to start playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, you basically have two options.

If you just want to change the state of the video player, what you can do is store a property at the App level, which you can then access from the kv file using `app.my_property`, or from the py file using `my_app = App.get_running_app()` and `my_app.my_property`. Then, whenever you need to, you can just check the property.

Option two is to set the video player screen to start playing whenever you switch to that screen, which would start the video playing when you press Load Video (since you currently have `on_press: root.manager.current = 'videoscr'`). To do that, you just need to implement an `on_enter()` (and/or `on_pre_enter()`) method for your screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I went with option two and it worked like a charm. Will also add an edit to my question to show others in a similar situation.